# How can I draw regular polygons along the horizontal axis?

Tags: mathematics

I drew simple [triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave) (that you can see It on [graph toy](http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/graphtoy/)).

[image: triangle wave]

```
   f1(x) = frac(x/(PI+5))*(PI+5)
   f2(x) = frac(-x/(PI+5))*(PI+5)
   f3(x) = min(f1(x),f2(x))*1.5
```

---

I want to change above shape like [Approximating Pi](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hmcutwfumj) and repeat It periodically along the horizontal axis.

[image: Approximating Pi]

then I want to cut negative parts of the vertical axis:

[image]

## Update

Note that I know how can I draw It by shader In [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XsVyzR).I Just need drawing mathematics In desmos or graphtoy,because I want Extract values of wave.I want to create polygon [wave form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveform).

I drew Periodic shape that I want to change the number of polygons
[Desoms Link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gh7fmcrbys).

Comment: I'm not familiar with graphtoy, but I think I can explain how to do this in terms of raw math - would that help?

Comment: @Pikalek Anyway, I'd appreciate if you answer my question

Answer (score 1):

You can use the equation of a circle to do this. A circle can be drawn using the equation:

$r^2 = x^2 + y^2$

You can solve for the upper half of this by rewriting it in terms of $y$ like this:

$y^2 = r^2 - x^2$

so

$y = ±√(r^2 - x^2)$

But we only want the positive half. So we say just:

$y = √(r^2 - x^2)$

You can then repeat it by using (((x - 2) % 4) - 2) as the input value. In the end the equation is this:

$y = √(1^2 - (((x - 2) mod 4) - 2)^2)$

It looks like this:

[image: semicircles]

In graph toy, it would be:

```
sqrt(1 - pow((((abs(x) - 2) % 4) - 2),2))
```

Comment: I think the OP wants arbitrary regular polygons though, like in the Desmos they linked, not just circles.

Comment: Instead of using sqrt I think `max(sin(x),0)` is better

Comment: @NathanReed that's right I need regular polygons not just circles